# Collect the first element of vectors inside a vector

Tags: rust, vector

I need to transform `Vec<Vec<<Value>>` (Value is the type in GSheets API that looks like this: `String("some text")`) into a single vector, what would be most efficient way to do it?

In my attempt I succeeded to isolate the very first String with `let data = res.1.values.unwrap().into_iter().nth(0).unwrap().into_iter().nth(0).unwrap().to_string();` and I could potentially iterate over the main vector and push each time the first item into a new vector but I wonder if there is not a better way (using collect or map?)

Also it is really verbose to convert the `Vec<Vec<< Value>>` into a single `String`,
is it normal to have to repea `unwrap()` everytime? (not bashing Rust, just wondering if there is a more concise way to do it).

Answer (score 2):

This is the cheapest flattening of whole `Vec<Vec<T>>` I have invented. It does 0 to 1 heap allocation in all cases.

If you have 0 to 1 element in `vec_2d` it will always perform 0 heap alloc.

If you went the idiomatic way, that is `vec_2d.into_iter().flatten().collect()`, I'm afraid you would get log2(n) heap allocs., where n is length of output vector, because I doubt that the compiler can predict n and preallocate once.

```
type Val = Option<String>;

fn flatten_cheaply(mut vec_2d: Vec<Vec<Val>>) -> Vec<Val> {
    // You want to reuse the buffer of the first 1-dim vector.
    // But if you did `.remove(0)`, it is O(n) complexity.
    // So just get a reference to it for now.
    let Some(first) = vec_2d.first_mut() else {return vec![];};
    // This is a smart trick for popping first element.
    // It has very little overhead because `Vec::new()` doesn't perform heap allocation.
    let mut flat_vec = std::mem::replace(first, Vec::new());
    // Then you want to do manual space reservation to be sure it happens only once.
    let needed_space = vec_2d.iter().skip(1).map(|vec_1d| vec_1d.len()).sum();
    flat_vec.reserve(needed_space);
    // Now you just collect what hasn't been in the first “vec_1d”.
    flat_vec.extend(vec_2d.into_iter().skip(1).flatten());
    // Everything is collected into `flat_vec`.
    flat_vec
}

fn main() {
    // Your input data as 2-dim table.
    let vec_2d: Vec<Vec<Val>> = [["text11", "text12"], ["text21", "text22"]]
        .map(|subarr| subarr.map(|s| Some(s.to_owned())).into())
        .into();
    // Your now flatten (1-dim) table.
    let vec_1d = flatten_cheaply(vec_2d);
    dbg!(&vec_1d);
}
```

Analogously, here you have cheap collecting of only the first column of 2D table represented by `Vec<Vec<Val>>`.

It will skip all rows of 2D table that are empty and won't panic.

```
    type Val = Option<String>;
    
    fn collect_firsts(mut vec_2d: Vec<Vec<Val>>) -> Vec<Val> {
        // You want to reuse the buffer of the first 1-dim vector.
        // But if you did `.remove(0)`, it is O(n) complexity.
        // So just get a reference to it for now.
        let Some(first) = vec_2d.first_mut() else {return vec![];};
        // This is a smart trick for “popping” first element.
        // It has very little overhead because `Vec::new()` doesn't perform heap allocation.
        let mut flat_vec = std::mem::replace(first, Vec::new());
        flat_vec.truncate(1);
        // Then you want to do manual space reservation to be sure it happens only once.
        let needed_space = vec_2d.len() - 1;
        flat_vec.reserve(needed_space);
        // Now you just collect other “firsts” skipping the first `vec_1d`.
        flat_vec.extend(
            vec_2d
                .into_iter()
                .skip(1)
                .flat_map(|vec_1d| vec_1d.into_iter().next()),
        );
        // Everything element from first column to 2D table is collected into `flat_vec`.
        flat_vec
    }
    
    fn main() {
        let vec_2d: Vec<Vec<Val>> = [["text11", "text12"], ["text21", "text22"]]
            .map(|subarr| subarr.map(|s| Some(s.to_owned())).into())
            .into();
    
        let firsts = collect_firsts(vec_2d);
        dbg!(&firsts);
    }
```

Comment: Awseome! Is there a quick and easy way to compare the assembly code output with `let flattened: Vec<_> = v.into_iter() .map(|inner| inner[0]).collect();` ?

Comment: You can use compiler explorer "https://godbolt.org/".  
But remember that `flatten_cheaply` is equivalent of `vec_2d.into_iter().flatten().collect()`, whereas  
`v.into_iter()
        .map(|inner| inner[0])
        .collect();` collects only first elements from each 1-dim vector.

Comment: I added another method named `collect_firsts` to my answer, so you can compare it to `v.into_iter().map(|inner| inner[0]) .collect()` which is it's equivalent **not of flattening**.

Comment: I am not convinced that it is necessary to pre-allocate the size even for the `flatten` case. `collect` uses `Iterator::size_hint` to allocate the initial size, and `flatten` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/iter/adapters/flatten.rs.html#488) the size hint to take the inner iterators into account. It would definitely be interesting to benchmark it though.

Comment: when you allocate the size, you allocate for a Vec<Value> or a Vec<String> ? I need to return Vec<String>

Comment: It's **not** `malloc` from C.  
`Vec::<T>::reserve` is generic over `T` size.  
But if you're changing the type on the fly, from `Val` to `String`, you need a different code than the one I provided. One of the main advantages of my code is reusing the buffer of the first nested vector, but it's hard to reuse buffer for different type.   

BTW `String` has the same memory layout and size as `type Val = Option<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) to convert a `Vec` of `Vec`s into a single `Vec`:

```rust
fn main() {

    let v = vec![
        vec!["hello".to_owned(), "there".to_owned()], 
        vec!["beautiful".to_owned(), "world".to_owned()]
    ];

    let flattened: Vec<_> = v.into_iter()
                             .flatten()
                             .collect();

    println!("{:?}", flattened);

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cbd6577a2c93a3c97859ff973dbe28f0)

Outputs:

```
["hello", "there", "beautiful", "world"]
```

If you want to collect the first string from each inner `Vec` then you could use this:

```rust
let flattened: Vec<_> = v.into_iter()
        .map(|inner| inner.into_iter().next().unwrap())
        .collect();
```

Note that this still contains an unwrap, to deal with the scenario that one of the inner arrays do not contain any elements. With `unwrap` it would panic.

Also note that both of these consume the original value. If you need to preserve the original value, replace `into_iter()` with `iter()` and clone the values as needed:

```rust
let flattened: Vec<_> = v.iter()
        .map(|inner| inner[0].clone())
        .collect();
```

Or, if you want an output array that references, rather than consumes or clones:

```rust
let flattened: Vec<_> = v.iter()
        .map(|inner| &inner[0])
        .collect();
```

The indexing operation (`[]`) will panic if you try to index outside the range of the `Vec`, so these would both panic if any of the inner vecs are empty.

Comment: with `let flattened: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(|inner| inner[0]).collect();` I get this error message: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Vec<JsonValue>>`
move occurs because value has type `Vec<JsonValue>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait" with inner[0] underline

Comment: You are correct @AntoninGAVREL - I forgot that my inner array contained static string slices which can be copied. I've updated the answer and added a few more options.

Comment: if I print it, it is still a Vec<Value>, not Vec<&str> or Vec<String>, but at least it compile! Also curious about `Vec<_> ` why does it work while if I replace with `Vec<String>` it doesnt?

Comment: Ok I got it right with:

Comment: `let data: Vec<_> = res.1.values.unwrap().iter().map(|inner|inner[0].as_str().unwrap().to_owned()).collect();` thank you!